# Xcode 8.0 simulator is showing black screen while running iOS app using ionic framework

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode8, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 framework for iOS app. My app is running with actual device but when I'm using xcode 8.0 simulator then i'm getting only black screen.

I want to run my app in simulator for debug and take screenshot of different sizes of screens.

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Have you assigned initial view controller?

Comment: @RinkiNegi Yes, i've assigned everything correctly, app is running fine with actual device with both android and iOS. The only thing is its not opening with xcode simulator. Simulator is opening with black screen.

Comment: @RinkiNegi My problem is solved now, Actually it takes time for launch app in simulator. Firstly it will take 5-10 mins and after that run without any problem. Thanks !!!